# Tweaking a Excel Pivot Table to display a OrderNumber instead of a calculation?

Tags: excel-2007, pivot-table

Using Microsoft Excel 2007 (or 2002) is it possible to create pivot data like this?

[image]

Specifically I would like to know if I can display '01(Y 0)' as a non-calculated text value instead of just a SUM/COUNT/MAX/etc value.

Comment: I do not think you can do this with a pivot table, but if you are content with a flat table as illustrated above, you can create it with ADO in Excel.

Comment: @Remou - Can you point me towards any documentation that may help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

With ADO

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

''This is not the best way to refer to the workbook
''you want, but it is very convenient for notes
''It is probably best to use the name of the workbook.

strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

''Note that if HDR=No, F1,F2 etc are used for column names,
''if HDR=Yes, the names in the first row of the range
''can be used.
''This is the Jet 4 connection string, you can get more
''here : http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

''Late binding, so no reference is needed

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "TRANSFORM First(t.[Order Number]) AS OrdNo " _
    & "SELECT t.[Slot Number], t.Time " _
    & "FROM [Sheet2$] t " _
    & "GROUP BY t.[Slot Number], t.Time " _
    & "PIVOT t.Company"


rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3


''Pick a suitable empty worksheet for the results

With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
        .Cells(1, i) = rs.Fields(i - 1).Name
    Next

    .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
End With

''Tidy up
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```